# Move window to right/left workspace shortcut

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I am looking for the **keyboard** shortcut of "Move to workspace Right/Left"

Like this:

[image: Right]

*I'm using compiz cube, with 4 horizontal workspaces*

(I'm not looking for "Move to another Workspace" shortcut)

Comment: Is thee a way to do this without keyboard shortcut when window is maximized?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033069/how-move-window-to-left-right-workspace

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I assume you are running Unity. You need to:

1. Install [compizconfig-settings-manager](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager)
2. Open it (it can be found by typing `ccsm` into the dash)
3. Scroll down and in the "Window Management" section activate the "Put" plug-in by ticking the box next to "Put" (*)
4. Press the "Put" button to configure the shortcut
5. The settings you are looking for are Bindings > Put to adjacent viewport > Viewport left/right/top/bottom
6. To avoid having the desktop chase every window you move (effectively reducing the effect of this option to "Switch workspace with window"), tick Misc. Bindings > Unfocus window

(*): Due to problems in compiz, at this step your screen is likely to freeze for anywhere between 5 and 30 seconds... just wait for your desktop to become responsive again. If you end up at a broken desktop, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, log in using your username and password and type `DISPLAY=:0 unity --replace &`, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and everything should come back.

Comment: This one work fine, it just have 1 problem, when I move the windows to another workspace, the cube rotates following the window. Is there anyway to make it just move the window without moving into workspaces?

Comment: Yup. CCSM > Put plugin > Misc Options > Unfocus window

Comment: You no longer need compizconfig-settings-manager to do this.  Ubuntu has default shortcuts and they can be edited in Ubuntu's "keyboard" settings panel.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 29):

In Ubuntu 14.04 (and probably earlier versions), there is a default key-binding of `Shift-Ctrl-Alt-[arrow]`.  E.g. to move the current window one workspace to the right, use `Shift-Ctrl-Alt-Right`.

The key-binding can be edited in Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts->Navigation.

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04 `Shift + Ctrl + Alt + Arrow` is still working

Comment: Not in Kubuntu 16.04...

Comment: This is a lifesaver, the "Workspace Switcher" in 16.04 is super buggy and I'm terrified to use it.

Comment: It not working in ubuntu 18.04 with grid-enabled workspaces. Does anybody know hot to solve this in ubuntu 18.04 gnome environement?

Comment: @KhalilLaleh I had an issue with Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome on setting the split to left shortcut which didn't work even if it was set in Settings -> Keyboard. I had to see what command was also bound to this shortcut, and I was able to do it with: `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings`, then I had removed the responsive shortcut that was bothering me with `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left "['disabled']"`. You may also check out if you have other command bind to the shortcut you are trying to use.

Answer (score 13):

I am using a probably an old styled shortcut, which is indeed simple.

I am using Desktop Wall instead of the Cube, which is awesome but I got tired of the cube, then I switched to Desktop Wall. Which features key bindings for "Move within wall", "Move with window within wall" and a few other. I have the default setup which includes Shift+Control+Alt+[Key] (left, right, etc.) in order to "move" the window to the desired wall. As shown here:

[image]

The Cube features the same binding options in the appropriate tab inside of the "Rotate desktop cube", which may be useful for you as you can define several combinations for your desired key bindings in order to move your windows to a specific Face (n) (of the cube).

[image]

If you are using more than a single horizontal workspace, then you probably have a 4 faces cube with dual workspaces, which means: only one cube, with selective workspace. This way, you can combine both the Desktop wall key bindings with the Rotate Cube key bindings in order to obtain the effect that you expect to.

But you should first check if the normal Shift+Control+Alt+[Key] (left, right, etc.) are doing the trick. Otherwise this workaround may be tricky for you. (not tested by me, I am not using the cube anymore).

***WARNING:*** The "Move to another Workspace" option in the context menu is simply dropping the window to the chosen workspace leaving you in the current workspace. The "Move with window [...]" will make you "fly" to the given workspace with the window.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Geppettvs, but I'll stay with pablomme solution (:

Comment: I think that this shortcut, Shift+Control+Alt+Arrow-Key has always worked from install.  Up, down, left or right.

Comment: yes it does but I can't say for sure if it does on plain ubuntu installs with compiz. I am using a different distro. But thank you for the information @lqlarry

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 12 and above you do this in Settings->Keyboard->Short cuts->Navigation

Answer (score 2):

Use gsettings not dconf, cf. https://kubos.cz/2018/07/19/ubuntu-18-workspaces-grid

e.g.
`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-right "['<Shift><Ctrl><Alt>Right']"`

etc

Answer (score 1):

You can use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 16.04

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>  to go window up
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>  to go window down
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd>  to go window right
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>  to go window left

[image]