# How move window to left/right workspace

Tags: gnome-shell, workspace-switcher, window-management

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- DE: Gnome 3.28.1

I switch from Unity to Gnome with new LTS Ubuntu.

In "old-new" GUI, i found that by default we don't have **horizontal** workspaces, and must move between workspaces **only in vertical order**.

I fixed it with gnome-shell-extension "Workspace Grid". Changed necessary shortcuts to switch workspace (view).

But in Gnome-keyboard settings no shortcuts for move **Application's Window** (not view) left/right **workspace** (not monitor).

How can I change this?

As workaround solution I guess only using shortcuts to move window to concrete workspace.

In **Settings** > **Devices** > **Keyboard** > **Navigation** *section*

I don't have necessary shortcuts preferences

[image]

Comment: Looks like you're stuck with up and down only. Haven't seen options limited in that way before. Would go back vertical workspaces and treat it cognitively as previous/next. Then change the shortcuts to whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `gsettings`, not `dconf`, see [this](https://kubos.cz/2018/07/19/ubuntu-18-workspaces-grid). e.g.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-right "['<Shift><Ctrl><Alt>Right']"
```

etc

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue. Found the settings for this using dconf-editor, under

- `org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/move-to-workspace-left` and
- `org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/move-to-workspace-right`.

The default keybindings are <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd> but you can change them to whatever you like.

Comment: helps to me, thanks! But default keybindings doesn't move anything. But when i changed it to custom all starting work fine

Answer (score 1):

Check your keyboard settings panel. Here's a snapshot of how it looks in 17.10, and you may just have to re-enable them in 18.04.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It's move of view to next workspace. I told about moving application's WINDOW to horizontal side WORKSPACE.

Comment: @mikewoe You weren't clear on that in your original edit of your question. You've edited it now. In 18.04, you don't see those options in keyboard shortcuts in the same area as I show? If not, then I'd go to https://extensions.gnome.org and see if there's a GNOME extension to do that for you.

Comment: In previous version I wrote about window move, too. my edit was more about text decoration for better understanding. I have same options, yes, and there is no options about horizontal moving.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu, I switched vertical workspace to *horizontal* using [Gnome Horizontal workspaces Extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2141/horizontal-workspaces/). Now my default Gnome shortcut keys are:

| Shortcut | Action |
| --- | --- |
| <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> | Move Window To Right Side Workspace |
| <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> | Move Window To Left Side Workspace |
| <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> | Switch To Right Side Workspace |
| <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> | Switch To Left Side Workspace |

Comment: Edited By @Matigo [Matigo](https://askubuntu.com/users/1091774/matigo)

Comment: No reproducible process given. What extension?

Comment: @RandyCragun used https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2141/horizontal-workspaces/

Comment: This plugin disables vertical workspaces. Is it like that for everyone else?

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 18.04, I found that the shortcuts are Super+Left and Super+Right.

[image: Settings > Keyboard]