# Why does Gnome3 ignore <Control><Shift><Alt> keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I've been having this problem: [How move window to left/right workspace](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033069/how-move-window-to-left-right-workspace) irritate me, ever since starting to use Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome (I also ended up having to use gnome-shell-extension "Workspace Grid") - so I tried looking a bit more into it.

I've found that, basically, all shortcuts with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> are ignored; for instance, here is `dconf-editor` showing the WM keybindings:

[image: dconf-editor-wm-keybindings]

Here, if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> nothing happens, however <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd> works. I tried some other shortcuts, and it seems, for instance, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> shortcuts work.

Also, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> (which should be move-to-workspace-left) seems to do the same as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> (switch-to-workspace-left), so it seems that specifically <kbd>Shift</kbd> is ignored when also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> are pressed ?!

So, my questions are:

- Why does this happen? Is it some policy in Gnome3 that prohibits <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>, and if so, why? If not, could this be a conflict with some other software (maybe the "Workspace Grid" extension itself)?
- How could I find out what, if anything, is consuming <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> keyboard shortcuts?

For the second issue, I've seen [Where does Ubuntu store its keyboard shortcut configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101226/where-does-ubuntu-store-its-keyboard-shortcut-configuration) - and trying `xev`; it seems `xev` can register (slow, consecutive) presses (and holds) of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>, then <kbd>Alt</kbd> - and also then key <kbd>Left</kbd> - which means the wm ignored <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> completely?!

Is there any other application (terminal or GUI), where I could press a keyboard shortcut, and it tells me what in the system interprets that shortcut?

Comment: Does this do what you want? https://www.keyboardtester.com/

Comment: Do you have multiple input languages? If so, did you activate any custom keyboard layout switcher shortcut?