# Cannot move window to another workspace Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, workspaces

Two days ago I installed Ubuntu 18.04. I have a few problems with it and one of them is that I cannot move a window do another workspace.

I try to do this with a shortcut. I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>. However, this only switches my workspace and nothing else happens.

Has someone an idea how this can be fixed? If you want some additional info, please do not hesitate to ask. Here is a screenshot of my shortcuts:

[image: screenshot of my shortcuts]

Comment: It seems that it can't handle all 3 shift-ctrl-alt on the same shortcut. I've changed it to shift-ctrl-down. But I'm not satisfied with that! Maybe using the ccsm as presented in this thread can do the trick! https://askubuntu.com/questions/98872/move-window-to-right-left-workspace-shortcut

Comment: I migrate to Unity UI and after this everything working perfectly. I have even monitors problem and it is fixed now!
Thanks for your attention!

Comment: I also couldn't make it work with ctrl+alt+shift+DOWN combination, so I have stayed with ctrl+super+alt+DOWN which is accepted.

Answer (score 21):

Try the following key combination:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow key (Left/Right/Up/Down)</kbd>.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

- <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd>
- <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd>

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-workspaces-movewindow.html.en

Answer (score 3):

Some applications (for example TWS trading java platform from Interactive Brokers) would not allow to move it's main window with mentioned in other answers hot keys (even though all other applications allow to do so).

So here's the "Universal Method" for stubborn apps like this (tested in Gnome):

Hit "window" key once - it should show you "Activities overview" with all your apps tiled and you'll notice all your workspaces "preview" vertical bar on the right side of the screen.

From here you can drag-n-drop you app window to the desired workspaces in the "preview" vertical bar.

Hope it helps!

Comment: 1.) "Hit "window" key once" — it's called the "Activities overview" 2.) It's called "drag-n-drop" :)

Comment: @Levente, haaaaha!-)) drug-n-drop was the fun one :-)))  Thank you, Levente!

Answer (score 2):

From Ubuntu 18.04 onwards, the keyboard shortcuts to transfer windows between workspaces in Unity desktop environment have changed.

For the GNOME desktop environment it is simple: open *Activities* → drag and drop.

For the Unity desktop environment however:

- For Ubuntu 16.04 and lower: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>arrow keys</kbd>
- For Ubuntu 18.04 and above:

  - To move window to workspace above → <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd>
  - To move window to workspace below → <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd>
  - To move window to workspace right → <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>
  - To move window to workspace left → <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>

At least for me it works.